# Git Rebasing issue

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I'm basically brand new to Git and am having some trouble rebasing. I had 9 commits on my branch - and I wanted to squash some of them together. So, in IntelliJ I did

```
git rebase -I
```

and went into the file and successfully altered my commits so that there are now only 7 commits. However, I then went to push to GitHub, and now, instead of altering the previous commits, it added the 7 commits as new and so there are 16 commits sitting on my branch.

How do I get my rebase to alter and not re-add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a rebase, which by the way you would typically never want to do on your repository's main branches (i.e. develop or master) you would need to do a force push, i.e. `git push -f`.  This is due to the fact that the history of the repository has been changed, and as a result, you have to "overwrite" the history that is stored in the GitHub version of the repository.  When you pushed your changes, did you do a force push?

Comment: I did not. But, when I just tried it, it told me "Everything up to date" and didn't overwrite anything...

Comment: Assuming everything went fine with the interactive rebase that you describe, I don't see how you wouldn't have had to do a force push :-(  Does your branch still have the correct 7 commits that you would expect?